# How to send an image with JDA

Tags: java, discord

im developing my Java bot for discord. And I want to send an image. I tried using `TextChannel.sendFile(File, Message)`, but it`s not that **result that I want to get**. I want this file to be displayed like a **normal image**.

The imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.MessageBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
```

And the other code:

```
        URL url = new URL(s.toString());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(conn.getInputStream());
        final List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent e = reader.nextEvent();

            if (e.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement se = e.asStartElement();

                if (se.getName().getLocalPart().equals("post")) {
                    Attribute purl = se.getAttributeByName(new QName("file_url"));
                    files.add(purl.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        int rid = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(files.size() - 1);
        String p = files.get(rid);
        files.clear();

        URL u = new URL(p);

        final String[] dots = p.split("\\.");
        final String format = dots[dots.length - 1];

        File f = new File("its not a porn." + format);

        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, f);

        Message m = new MessageBuilder().append("okay :)").build();
        c.sendFile(f, m).queue();
}
```

I tried to find a solution somewhere but i haven found any info that could help.

Comment: share code, do you use `sx.blah.discord.Discord4J` ?

Comment: @IddoE i need to include this in my build path, right? Then how i do that using discord4j?

Comment: share current code so we can help, I only asked because I see an example with this library

Comment: @IddoE no i dont have this in my project

Comment: @IddoE added in question. Im using JDA

Comment: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA ?

Comment: @IddoE yup, this one :D

Comment: educational guess, & share your imports, please try to give complete code example for your specific issue

Comment: @IddoE added imports :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the docs, you need to create a [MessageEmbed](http://home.dv8tion.net:8080/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/MessageEmbed.html) and add it to the message using m.setEmbed(..)

Answer (score 1):

At JDA 4.2.0_168

the message on sendFile() is the name of the file that you are sending to the discord servers, so it needs an extension

example:

```java
File f = new File("image.png");
TextChannel.sendFile(f, "image.png").queue();
```

if you want comments in the message

```java
File f = new File("image.png");
//the name doesn't need to be the same, just the same extension
TextChannel.sendFile(f, "another_name.png").append("okay :)").queue();
```

[Result of last code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHPsj.png)